# Clean project error with databinding: Unable to delete file androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters--setter_store.json

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I use Databinding. Sometimes while I make changes project may be broken. Then I go to *Build -> Clean project & Re-Build project*. And I get some strange error:

```
Unable to delete file: {path_to_project}\app\build\intermediates\data_binding_dependency_artifacts\debug\dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug\out\androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters--setter_store.json
```

Every time I don't know how to fix it, because I get this error on clean or rebuild. Even if I make *Invalidate caches / Restart* the problem isn't gone.

If I try to delete this file manually I get error that file is using by another process. Then I close project and successfully delete this file. But when I open the project and build it I get the same error described above.

As I can see the problem is about databinding, but I'm not sure because I saw the same problem with other files from other users on StackOverflow. Sometimes problem is gone by itself, but usually it isn't. Maybe the problem occurs because of errors in layout files, but how to find it out if there is no errors in build log.

Has anyone meet that error? Any ideas how to fix that situation without crush whole the project in undefined time range?

Comment: `gradlew --stop` followed by `gradlew clean` Command solved my problem

Comment: Jesus this is so annoying, it's only been introduced within the last month

Comment: You find any solution or not?  I am also facing same problem

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya As I can see it may happens when you make changes to any binding stuff, but forgot to change it in layout or made some mistake. It's difficult to handle errors in layouts, because there is no syntax highlight. So, you need to look for some mistakes you could make. If it doesn't help itself, you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569622/10330688 I'm not sure if it works, but sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is still here but all answers don't solve it. Project doesn't compile for a reason, usually it's some kind of mistake, and **if you just delete build folder** (which contains file Android Studio is unable to delete) **it will not solve problem**.

When you are trying to compile project you may get a dozens of errors in generated files (databinding, room, etc). Unfortunatelly, errors are not displaying in the usual window, but if you expand this generated files with errors, you probably will see the real problem, **your mistakes you didn't fix** when was changing your classes related to generated files. **Just fix these mistakes and compile project again.** Note: *you probably should to look at warnings too.*

But if you already got error `Unable to delete file` you won't see errors in generated files. You need to restart Android studio (if it won't help, you need to delete app\build) and try to compile your project. After that you will find generated files with errors in build tab.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Definitely this was the case for me, some mistake on the code that ends up showing this message, unfortunately Android Studio doesn't display all correct messages yet to guide us to a solution. Thanks for sharing this with us.

Answer (score 4):

I close Android Studio, delete the app\build folder then reopen Android Studio. Note that all instances of AS must be closed for Windows to let you delete the build folder.

Answer (score 3):

Put Below command in Android Studio terminal.

**`gradlew --stop`**

Comment: This was enough for me to solve the problem **without** closing and reopening Android Studio, which was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First follow this 4 steps

- Remove your file generated (build folder)
- Clean your project ( simply run cmd command - > `gradlew clean`)
- Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
- Restart computer

If not helpful please try following steps

- Gradle sync;
- Reinstall Java JRE & Java SDK;
- Reinstall the latest version of Android Studio
- Rolling back to the previous AS version
- Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
- Delete the gradle and .gradle directories in the project directory;
- Delete the .gradle directory in your directory;
- Run gradlew clean ( simply run cmd command - > `gradlew clean`)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and tried the method mentioned above. I could not find the related class in the error message when I searched in the project directory.

In the end, I suspected that it maybe `~/.gradle` problem, and then recompile after deleting, and finally solved.

```
mv ~/.gradle ~/.gradle_bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the daemon and parallel build in `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.parallel=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the solutions above but seemed not to find them working. 
But here is what I did to get my project up and running again.

I am assuming this is happening because you are using dataBinding.
browse to the dataBinding section in your app gradle file

now disable dataBinding by setting to false.
next, rebuild your project and you will notice an error about something to deal with missing a dataBinding in xml file.

Next enalble dataBinding by setting to true this time.
next, rebuild your project.

It should have cleared that strange error.

Forgive me for the strange explanation but am new to contributing to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of databinding cache issue. We need to delete that cache by disabling it first. I solved the issue after changing the properties of the gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.parallel=false
android.enableBuildCache=false
org.gradle.caching= false
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

and

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = false
    }
```

Clean and rebuild the project. After rebuilding it will show errors. Then change all the configuration (make all properties true) and clean, rebuild. It will work absolutely fine.